# Trying to redirect to component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to redirect in react.At the start, I am just loading a simple signup with. It is just a simple page without any navigation menu.
[image]

[image]
[image]

When the user clicks admin. He should be redirected to admin portal and if clicks student he should be redirected to student portal as being shown in the images.

This is my App.js file.

```
class App extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
       
        <div className="container">
            <Nav userState="/" />
           
            <Footer />
        </div>
       
    );
}
}
```

This is my nav.js file.

```
function StudentRender() {
return(
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <a className="navbar-brand">Student Portal</a>
        <div className="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/studentHome" className="nav-link active" aria- 
     current="page">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/studentAddCourses" className="nav-link" aria-current="page">Add 
 Courses</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/studentContactForm" className="nav-link" aria- 
current="page">Contact Form</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                <li style={{ fontWeight: 'bolder' }} type="button" className="nav-item" data- 
  toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    <a className="nav-link" >Login</a>
                </li>
                <li style={{ fontWeight: 'bolder' }} className="nav-item hide-signup-button" 
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">
                    <p style={{ marginBottom: 'margin-bottom: 0px !important' }} 
    className="nav-link">|</p>
                </li>
                <li style={{ fontWeight: 'bolder' }} type="button" className="nav-item hide- 
   signup-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mySignupModal">
                    <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">register </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
)
}
function AdminRender() {
return(
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <a className="navbar-brand">Admin Portal</a>
        <div className="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/search" className="nav-link active" aria- 
current="page">Search</Link>
                    {/* <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" 
href="index.html">Home</a> */}
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/delete" className="nav-link" aria-current="page">Delete</Link>
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/add" className="nav-link" aria-current="page">Add</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/list" className="nav-link" aria-current="page">List</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/forms" className="nav-link" aria-current="page">Forms</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        {/* <div>
                 <ul className="navbar-nav">
                     <li style={{ fontWeight: 'bolder' }} type="button" className="nav-item" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                         <a className="nav-link" >Login</a>
                     </li>
                     <li style={{ fontWeight: 'bolder' }} className="nav-item hide-signup- 
button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">
                         <p style={{ marginBottom: 'margin-bottom: 0px !important' }} 
className="nav-link">|</p>
                     </li>
                     <li style={{ fontWeight: 'bolder' }} type="button" className="nav-item 
hide-signup-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mySignupModal">
                         <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">register </Link>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </div> */}
    </div>
</nav>
)
}
```

I am rendering admin navigation or student navigation based on the userState value

```
class Nav extends React.Component
{

constructor(props)
{
    super(props)
    this.state={
        userState : props.userState
    }
}


render() {
    debugger
    if (this.state.userState == "/") {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <h2>Bow Valley College- Course Registration Portal</h2>
                        <Login />
                        <Register />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
        
    }
    if (this.state.userState == "admin")
    
        return (
            <Router>
                <AdminRender />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/adminHome">
                        <Search />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <h2>Bow Valley College- Course Registration Portal</h2>
                        <Login />
                        <Register />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/search">
                        <Search />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/delete">
                        <Delete/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/add">
                        <Add/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/list">
                        <List/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/forms">
                        <Forms/>
                    </Route>


                    <Route path="/studentHome" exact>
                        <EnrolledCourses />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/" exact>
                        <h2>Bow Valley College- Course Registration Portal</h2>
                        <Login />
                        <Register />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/studentAddCourses">
                        <AddCourses />
                    </Route>
                    {/* <Route path="/studentAddCourse">
                    <AddCourse />
                </Route> */}
                    <Route path="/studentContactForm">
                        <ContactForm />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/register">
                        <Register />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    else if (this.state.userState == "student")
        return (
            <Router>
                <StudentRender />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/studentHome" exact>
                        <EnrolledCourses />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/" exact>
                        <h2>Bow Valley College- Course Registration Portal</h2>
                        <Login />
                        <Register />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/studentAddCourses">
                        <AddCourses />
                    </Route>
                    {/* <Route path="/studentAddCourse">
                    <AddCourse />
                </Route> */}
                    <Route path="/studentContactForm">
                        <ContactForm />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/register">
                        <Register />
                    </Route>


                    <Route exact path="/adminHome">
                        <Search />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <h2>Bow Valley College- Course Registration Portal</h2>
                        <Login />
                        <Register />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/search">
                        <Search />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/delete">
                        <Delete/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/add">
                        <Add/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/list">
                        <List/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/forms">
                        <Forms/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
}
}
```

As you can see I am trying the render the page first based on the userState value which is "/" at first.
Here is my signup page

```
adminSubmitEvent = (event) => {
    debugger
    return <Nav userState="admin"/>
   //return this.props.history.push("admin", { state: 'admin'}); 
    //verify registration and add it to db
   // alert(`Admin/employee with name: ${this.state.name} is registering`);
    //display message
    //navigate to admin protal
}
```

For the simplicity I am only showing the method that gets called when user click on the admin button to redirect to admin side. I did alot of research but haven't found a suitable asnwer. I tried to return the component but signup page just reloads. I tried to use history it didn't work either. Kindly help me out thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit unclear from *where* you are wanting to navigate from, and *where* you are wanting to navigate to. Where is `adminSubmitEvent` function declared and used? Are you wanting it to navigate to "/admin", or I guess "/" since you are rendering multiple routers for some reason? I guess you'd also need to trigger a state update in `Nav` to update `this.state.userState` so it renders the right component and admin routing. Can you clean up the extraneous code that isn't really relevant to the issue/question you have?

Comment: @DrewReese So the first page would be the signup page as you can see the in the image. This page has no navigation menu. When the user clicks student or admin button he should be redirected to the specified page with the related navigation menu on top which you can see in the second and third image. I just want to achieve that. The adminSubmitEvent is shown at the very last which is bind to admin button on the signup page. I am able to hit call the event but when I return  `<Nav "admin"/>`.  I have put the whole code to show I want to populate the specified menu in the navigation.

Comment: So this "signup" page/component with the buttons is the relevant code we need to see? I see you *had* a `history.push` in that `adminSubmitEvent`, why is it commented out?

Comment: It was commented because I was unfamiliar how useHistory works in react Hooks. Later I read about it carefully and made it work. I also had change my class component to function component in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can make the Student and Admin buttons as the links and use the corresponding paths for them and the proper navigation redirect should work.  I.e.

```
<Link to="/adminHome">Admin</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

SoI was able to use react hooks and navigated the user to different page. there I am passing admin | student based as a prop to Nav component. Which is updating my navigation accordingly. I am pretty new to react and not sure if this a viable solution or no but thank you everyone who commented and tried to help.

In my register page I am using react hooks

```
const studentSubmitEvent = (event) => {
    history.push("/studentNav")
  }
```

And in my AdminNav I am calling  Nav component with `admin` as prop

```
export default class AdminNav extends React.Component {
render() {
    debugger
    return (
        <div>

            
            <Nav userState="admin" prevPath={window.location.pathname}/>
           
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

And lastly in my Nav component I am checking the userState value and rendering the route according

```
  if (this.state.userState == "admin")
    
        return (
            <Router>
                <AdminRender />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/adminNav">
                        <Search />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/adminHome">
                        <Search />
                    </Route>
                    {/* <Route exact path="/">
                        <h2>Bow Valley College- Course Registration Portal</h2>
                        <Login />
                        <Register />
                    </Route> */}
                    <Route path="/search">
                        <Search />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/delete">
                        <Delete/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/add">
                        <Add/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/list">
                        <List/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/forms">
                        <Forms/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
```

`AdminRender` is displaying the navigation menu